# SQL: Reduce table by removing specified Items in a table

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following table in a vertica db:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| A     | B     | S     |
| S     | C     | D     |
| E     | F     | S     |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Each row represents a transaction (e.g. shopping in a store). I am looking for a scalable way to remove all `S` items in the table and than reduce the table to get this:

```
+-------+-------+
| Item1 | Item2 |
+-------+-------+
| A     | B     |
| D     | C     |
| E     | F     |
+-------+-------+
```

The order of the rows in the new table is not important.

Side note: Every row in the table has the item `S`, so there is no need to worry about `null` entries.

Follow up: What if I want to remove n items at the same time, is there a faster way than running the SQL query in question n times?

One possible solution would be to replace or add to the item in question the term `0000`. Than sort each row alphanumerically and delete the first column, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: The actual problem is your table design. It seems to be not normalized

Comment: @juergend can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If we might see a real example we can give some suggestions to a better DB structure. Currently this looks like you did not follow any design rules.

Comment: *Each row represents a transaction (e.g. shopping in a store)* Well, you need to be more specific. Why not add the real table structure with a little example data?

Comment: this is the real table structure, only with simplified values and a smaller table. but the general idea ist just to remove an entry from each row. is that not trivial in a sql? in matlab for example I would do this in two lines.

Comment: It is not trivial in SQL. And having numbers in column names is almost always an indicator of bad table design. You should not have more than one item in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve in a funky way.

1. Create a string from all the rows using `||`
2. Remove the part of the string that you don't want
3. Split the string up using `SPLIT_PART`

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    SPLIT_PART(replace, ';', 2) AS c1, 
    SPLIT_PART(replace, ';', 3) AS c2 
FROM 
    (SELECT replace (  ';'|| item1 ||';'|| item2 ||';'|| item3  ,     ';S'    ,     '') 
     FROM my_table ) AS temp
```

The way I see it this query can be easily generated (e.g. with python) for bigger tables, and it doesn't involve creating temporary tables.

Comment: Use `SPLIT_PARTB` if these are ASCII. It's faster.

Comment: Right now the items are acutally strings (varchar(300)), I am thinking to convert them into integers to speed up the process. This plus using `SPLIT_PARTB` should make the process much faster. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Integer might help, might not. You're going to have to convert them to varchar for this method either way. The savings you'd get would be more on the projection side (try to read less data etc).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple ways to do this. I would just first convert the `S` to `NULL`.  Then `COALESCE` to remove the `NULL` leaving only two values. Then I would use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` to sort the two values so you get a clean output.

Notice for the `COALESCE` I simply reverse the order so that in all cases (assuming only one `S` value per tuple) the two Items will be different.

```
with s_filtered as (
    select nullif(Item1,'S') Item1,
           nullif(Item2,'S') Item2,
           nullif(Item3,'S') Item3
    from mytable
)
select distinct least(coalesce(Item1,Item2)) Item1,
       greatest(coalesce(Item3,Item2)) Item2
from s_filtered
```

I'm not sure I understand what the scalable part of your question is in this case. If you mean that you want to have more than 3 Items, well... this method won't work too well. You can do it (minus the sort, which you'd have to do preprocess), but it'd be a lot of creative coalescing probably.

Alternatively, you could normalize and do some kind of analytical pivot after filtering out your `S` type.  This would better support more Items.

Example if you had 6 items with one `S` (note, you would need to tie things together with an id):

```
with ordered_mytable as (
    select id, item, row_number() over (partition by id order by item) rn
    from mytable
    where item <> 'S'
)
select id, 
       max(decode(rn,1,item)) Item1,
       max(decode(rn,2,item)) Item2,
       max(decode(rn,3,item)) Item3,
       max(decode(rn,4,item)) Item4,
       max(decode(rn,5,item)) Item5
from ordered_mytable
group by id
```

Comment: I am having trouble with your second approach, namely: Tie things together with an id. It seems that it is not trivial to add a new column with an id to the initial table in vertica. Maybe I am confused about the 'normalization' step, is it basically a union all over all rows to get two columns, one with the id and one with the data? But in order to accomplish that I would still need to add an id column first to the initial table, is there an easy way than this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741980/is-there-a-way-to-set-auto-increment-property-on-existing-table-column-in-vertic)

Comment: If it is temporary only for this process (like you are tossing it in a temporary / work table), you could use `row_number() over ()` maybe (but that is not static over multiple executions, could be different each run).  Depends on what you are doing, this might not work out. Or yes, you could add an identity column.  If you do that, then you'll need to make sure your sequence cache is set high enough to avoid frequent uncached pulls.